# Can I use jQuery to animate properties independently?

Tags: jquery

I would like to animate the sizes and position of elements independently in the interest of being able to use jQuery's `stop()` function to clear the queue for one property but not the other. I am only animating the `width` and `left` properties.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you mean "clear the queue of any 'left' animations but allow 'width'" or do you mean clear the queue only when you do one or the other?

Comment: I mean to clear the queue of any `left` animations but allow `width` to continue. Basically, like having two separate queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use jquery 1.7, but this can be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/jRawX/16/

As of 1.7, you can pass a string as the `queue` parameter.  This will queue the animation on a named queue instead of the fx queue.  Then when you call stop you can pass that same queue name.

```js
$(function() {

    $("#stopTop").click(function() {
        $("#t1").stop("topQueue", true);
    });

    $("#stopLeft").click(function() {
        $("#t1").stop("leftQueue", true);
    });

    $('#t1').animate({
        left: 100
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        queue: "leftQueue"
    }).animate({
        left: 600
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        queue: "leftQueue"
    }).animate({
        top: 100
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        queue: "topQueue"
    }).animate({
        top: 600
    }, {
        duration: 10000,
        queue: "topQueue"
    }).dequeue("topQueue").dequeue("leftQueue");
})
```

```css
    .tester {
        background:red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 400px;
        top: 300px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tester" id="t1"></div>

<button id="stopTop">Stop Top</button>
<button id="stopLeft">Stop Left</button>
```